# Valve configuration not working in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, tomcat-valve

I access my application with url i.e `https://myIPAddress:8443/myWebApp/`

I have created the `myWebApp.xml` file which contains below context element and placed it under `<tomcat_home>\conf\Catalina\localhost\`

```
<Context>
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.MySSLAuthenticator"/>
</Context>
```

MySSLAuthenticator.class is under jar file which is placed under `<tomcat_home>\lib`

But looks like MySSLAuthenticator is not coming into picture as i get below error where i see instance of SSLAuthenticator
not MySSLAuthenticator

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:266)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientCertificate(ServerHandshaker.java:1631)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:176)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.handShake(JSSESupport.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getPeerCertificateChain(JSSESupport.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:1120)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SSLAuthenticator.authenticate(SSLAuthenticator.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
```

i am not sure what is missing here? tomcat version is 6.0.35

Answer (score 1):

In your question there is no mention of an associated `Realm` definition, potentially that is what's causing the error (*null cert chain*). If there is no principal associated with the request (which is unlikely if there was no previous successful authentication performed), `SSLAuthenticator` will invoke the authentication realm. However, in your case this `Realm` may not exist or it does but is misconfigured in some way and as a result SSLAuthenticator can't interpret it.

You can validate this by disabling your custom `MySSLAuthenticator` and make it work with the built-in `SSLAuthenticator` first. Once you get that working, then try extending SSLAuthenticator. Assuming that that's what you're trying to do.

It is also advisable to set logging level to debug as you may find useful info logged from the extended classes:

[SSLAuthenticator](https://github.com/apache/tomcat60/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/SSLAuthenticator.java%20and%20its%20parent%20class) and its parent class [AuthenticatorBase](https://github.com/apache/tomcat60/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java)

With regards to your class not even being recognised by tomcat, the most likely answer is that you've defined it in an application context. Tomcat valves can be associated with the `Engine`, `Host` and `Context` and they are invoked in that order. So the most likely answer to why tomcat never reaches your `Valve` is that the built-in `SSLAuthenticator` captures (and falls over on) the request on the `Engine` level. So subsequent `Host` and `Context` level processing is never reached.